# Remove dollar sign from price of product in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to remove dollar sign "$" from the product price in a certain section of single-product page. Here's my code which is not working.Please help.

```
global $product;
$price = $product->get_price_html();
$filter_price = preg_replace('/.00/', '', $price);
$new_price = str_replace( '$', '', $filter_price );
echo $new_price;
```

Comment: There is no problem with your replacement code. The problem occurs with the way you are trying to get the price of the product. Where do you want to do these replaces?

Comment: I only need this replace in one section of product page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$price = $product->get_price();
$new_price = str_replace( '$', '', $price  );
echo $new_price;
```

If you want to get the price in a product template then you dont have to declare `global $product` again. Also, this will get you the actual price of the product before the apply of VAT. You can calculate the VAT manually afterwards.